# Or tools specifying a number of parallel workers more than 1 return an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, or-tools

Hello im new to or tools and im trying to use it to solve a scheduling porblem.
Im trying to use the solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 3 in my code to specify a number of parallel workers so i can achieve parallelism while solving but i get this error :

[image]

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, enumerating all solutions in parallel is not supported.

Comment: Is there any alternative or a solution to use parallelism because i just need one feasible solution?

Comment: Do not use enumerate_all_solutions.

Comment: yes i was using the SearchForAllSolution now i've changed it to SolveWithCallback function thank you for clarifying.

Comment: i have another question if you please i've used the SolveWith Callback method but it return to me an unknown status always at 0.9s and i don't know how to handle this type of status really what is limiting the solver or is UNKNOW the same as INFEASIBLE thanks in advance.

Comment: are you on windows ?